# Name of neurons affecting or being affected by a neuron?

Tags: neuroscience, terminology

This question is about terminology:

> By which established and catchy terms are the sets of neurons with
>   respect to a given neuron $N$ called which
>
> 1. directly affect $N$ synaptically
> 2. are directly affected by $N$ synaptically?

These terms came to my mind, but I am not sure which ones are most commonly used:

- the presynaptic/postsynaptic neurons of $N$
- the afferent/efferent neighbours of $N$
- the afferents/efferents of $N$
- the incoming/outgoing neurons of $N$
- the neurons projecting on/to $N$ vs. the neurons projected on/to by $N$

Or is there no such established term, and anything goes, depending on the context?

Answer (score 2):

At the simplest level, the terms 'pre-synaptic'/'post-synaptic' neurons should cover what you wish to describe.
'Afferent'/'efferent' are usually used to refer to axonal projections, usually between functionally distinct areas, or nerves. However, I wouldn't be too surprised if someone used these terms to refer to synaptically connected populations although I would consider it unusual. Simply, 'connected neurons' is also a term frequently used.

---

I will now go into a tangent to give you some background that should help you formulate an informed view about the vocabulary being used:

In areas that display a high degree of local connectivity, like the cerebral cortex and the hippocampus, any given neuron is connected with many different neurons. Hebb's theory of [***cell assemblies***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_ensemble) posits that a group of highly connected neurons may form over time in order to subsist a specific function. Given the high degree of connectivity, any given neuron will be able to participate in many different assemblies. It is often thought that these assemblies constitute the substrate of [***engrams***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebbian_theory), the physiological correlates of memory, at the level of the neuronal network. Hence, the concept of cell assemblies is prominent in our thinking about groups of synaptically connected neurons.

Setting aside the questions of the definition of the engram, recent efforts have claimed to identify engram cells under [this](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/356/6333/73) or [that](http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v16/n9/full/nrn4000.html) experimental paradigm, although the connectivity of those cells has not been established. While we know that [functionally similar neurons display a higher degree of connectivity](http://www.nature.com/doifinder/10.1038/nature17192) and that [groups of cells with correlated activity patterns can be formed by artifically-induced synchrony](http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/doi/10.1126/science.aaf7560), the direct link between increased connectivity and behaviourally relevance has not been established.

On the other hand, only a handful of studies have directly measured the connectivity between more than two neurons ([Song et al.](http://dx.plos.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.0030068), [Perin et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3069183/pdf/pnas.201016051.pdf)), revealing the intricate properties of neuronal network structure. Depending on the level of description they may refer to *distributed cell assemblies*, *synaptic clusters* of neurons, *$n$-vertex cliques*, and *motifs*.

All this is to say that as soon as you start considering more than a pair of neurons, it makes little sense to talk about neurons that are exclusively connected with each other. As every neuron is connected to almost all other neurons in its immediate neighbourhood we often focus on the functional implications of their connectivity. Under this light, the concept of cell assemblies is central in modern neuroscience.

---

Comment: I added "directly" to modify "affect" in the original question.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to reasonably answer this question is to say: "read some papers and follow their conventions" - it's much too hard to develop an exhaustive description of how all of those terms are used without creating an answer that's much too broad. I'll give some comments, though:

Presynaptic/postsynaptic is most often used in the context of synaptic transmission/plasticity/etc where the subject is a synapse. You would not typically say presynaptic neurons to N when you are really just talking about a network from A to N.

Afferent/efferent 'neighbors' I have never heard used, won't claim it never is but it seems completely wrong to me.

As for afferents/efferents these refer to the *fibers* primarily. Those terms are most appropriate when you are talking about something like the spinal cord, where afferent projections head toward the CNS/brain and efferent projections head toward the periphery; in the brain I find them often confusing or incorrectly used. This is because the terms afferent and efferent don't actually refer to inputs and outputs, but rather to inward versus outward direction. Defining "direction" in the brain gets pretty ambiguous if you aren't talking specifically about primary sensory or motor areas.

Incoming/outgoing I rarely if ever hear.

In the context of "projecting" usually the noun form is used: *projections*, as in "thalamocortical projections" or "projections from V1 to V2." I'd say this is the least ambiguous/best terminology if you are talking about connections between different brain areas. Within a local brain area (i.e., a given nucleus or a region of neocortex) you would be less likely to use the term "projection" though it wouldn't necessarily be wrong.

Comment: But isn't the concept of "the set of neurons which directly affect neuron N synaptically" a very clear one, and would deserve a name? (And I *did* read more than just *some* papers, and didn't come up with a convention. Maybe because these sets aren't interesting and/or dealt with?)

Comment: It depends on context, but there's also no strict rules. If you are talking about just one cell in a computational fashion, you would probably just say "the inputs to cell X" but people would understand if you used some other terminology. I'd say this is typical of English in general, and maybe that gets carried over into scientific fields where English is the main lingua franca.

Comment: "Inputs to cell X" sounds good. Does "outputs from cell X" sounds good to you, too?

Comment: That's fine if you are talking about the outputs themselves; you could also use "targets of cell A" to describe the population that receives inputs from cell A.

Comment: You have to admit: terminology and wording is *not* very controlled and unequivocal in neurosciences.

Comment: .. which doesn't make life easier for the novices;-)

Comment: "Incoming/outgoing? I rarely if ever hear." 
I found this wording [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_motor_neuron#Connectivity).

Comment: @BryanKrrause: Just to let you  know: I feel offended and censored by you and your actions (e.g. closing my questions without giving me good reasons and opportunities to react). I find it indiscriminating and would like to flag it - but I can't because you are a moderator.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker I explained to you why your last question was deleted in a comment on that question (cross-posting), including a link to the relevant discussion on Meta. If you prefer to delete your question at Psych&Neuro instead, ping me here and I'll undelete. I downvoted rather than closing your question so as to *not* unilaterally close it; the deletion is separate from my reason for downvoting. If you have issue with my actions you can post to Meta, or see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges

Comment: Cross-posting is not prohibited per se, is it? The distinction between Biology and Psych&Neuro is hard to make, and how can I consider it beforehand? Why is it bad to post the same question twice when it is not clear where to find the better audience? Why is it to be "punished"?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Deleting a question doesn't "punish" anyone. Please read the meta I linked to you; I can link it again here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu I find it very rude to cross-post, because if a question is answered on one site, someone might still answer it on the other site despite it already having an answer. These sites have high bars for answers, and it often takes a lot of work to answer a question. It's rude to have someone take the time to answer an already-answered question.

Comment: Especially reference requests are not so hard to answer: If anyone knows a reference he/she just can give it. I deliberately did not ask for elaborate answers but just for a link. Personally, I cannot see anything rude in cross-posting reference requests. Finally and generally: What is bad with having two (independent) answers? Do you believe, every question can have only one correct answer?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker The problem is not having two independent answers, but having two independent *questions* that are the same question. In this case, the different answers end up in different places rather than the same place. Please please read the well-reasoned answers in the meta post I linked and don't make me rehash the entire discussion here, that's why I linked it for you.

Comment: But why not accept that there are questions that can equally well be posted at two SE sites? Why to force to ask them only at one site? Isn't it in turn a good opportunity to bridge gaps? (I understand your point better with respect to more or less **eduacted** SE sites like MathOverflow SE and Mathematics SE. But Biology and Psych&Neuro are on the same level.)

Comment: And be assured: Whenever I get an answer on one of the sites, I'll share it on the other - to the benefit of all!